Using Program Ids in Address Lookup Tables (missing documentation about LUTs)
It seems there are limitations on the types of accounts that can be passed through address lookup tables in a V0 message header, though these limitations aren't explicitly defined anywhere in the docs as of now (neither here nor here).

No signers: The most obvious limitation is that LUT addresses can't be signers (this is self-explanatory as there is no isSigner property to set when looking up an address)
No program ids: This is poorly documented and the exact limitations are unclear. So far I found out that:

An account with its executable flag set to true can in principle be part of a LUT lookup (for example if the program is never called)
An account referred to via program_id_index in one of a V0-message's instructions cannot be part of a LUT lookup (meaning that all programs used as part of the main instructions of a transaction cannot be looked up through a LUT). (source)
Unclear: Can a program account passed via AccountInfo as argument into an instruction be part of a LUT lookup, even if that program account is then used by the instruction as part of CPI (cross program invocation a.k.a. "inner instruction")?



In other words: If one wanted to reduce the amount of bytes of a Solana transaction with many instructions, would it be possible to move these instructions into a "wrapper" program which receives the program ids through a lookup table and executes the required instructions, thus saving the bytes needed to list the program ids of the programs involved in the inner instructions (CPIs)?

This is an excellent question!
You can definitely pass in a CPI program through an address lookup table. Take a look at account #36 in this Jupiter transaction, where the Token Program is listed as part of the address lookup table: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2Sca3UiTEaqQ7B9xPsL36gW8zRuBMRK5vDeUGG2Twe8zYfrVz1pwvAzbKHgRERsnDbVKQ6CUGCGJF1BiSQSafCCX
Here's another example where the Raydium AMM program (an upgradeable program) is in an address lookup table: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2wwHzHF5qJURVVY7B6L8Y8m7hGMoNpoycJQuCUs24G1m5dr9fJcSv5ua6ehNgcbc9wpMkMNSUskyhiHeUYQQmqdj

Just to clarify, this example shows address lookup tables DO NOT support compressing program IDs referenced in top-level instructions, but DO support compressing program IDs referenced in inner-instructions (CPIs).
